# Can't get python data to print to outfile

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write looped data to 'testing.txt' file with each result on a new line but the file does not generate anything. I get

> Error: TypeError: write() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

```
import requests

with open('testing.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for number in (4,8,5,7,3,10):
        url = requests.get('https://www.google.com/' + str(number))

        response =(url)
        results = response.content
        print(results)
        outfile.write('results', '/n')
        print (results, file=outfile)
```

Comment: Not writing anything at all? Or just the last result? Because the latter is what this code is doing.

Comment: Can  you show your console output?

Comment: And fix your indentation.

Comment: I'm trying to write the results of the loop, but when I put in outfile.write('results', '\n') I got an error message about write taking only one variable

Comment: That's because write only takes one variable :)

Comment: You also aren't writing anything in the loop

Comment: Did you intend `results + '\n'`?

Comment: Either `print(results, file=outfile)` or use `write` properly.

Comment: Other than that, `response =(url)` is an unnecessary variable assignment. It does nothing

Comment: No, `outfile.write()` indeed doesn't take two arguments. Have you tried passing in a *single* string? Try passing in `result` instead of the string literal `'result'` as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`response.text` instead of `response.content` is working for me.

```
import requests

def request_number(number):
    response = requests.get('https://www.google.com/' + str(number))
    return response.text

with open('testing.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    results = list(map(request_number, (4,8,5,7,3,10)))
    outfile.write("\n".join(results))
```

Edit: Another version closer to OP code (as requested in comments), also working for me:

```
import requests

with open('testing.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    results = []
    for number in (4,8,5,7,3,10):
        url = requests.get('https://www.google.com/' + str(number))

        response =(url)
        results.append(response.text)
        print(results)

    outfile.write("\n".join(results))
```

Comment: You've modified a lot of crucial things in the code but haven't addressed any of the actual problems OP is having.

Comment: Added another version, closer to OP code. Both codes were tested in my computer.

Comment: You're misunderstanding the point... `outfile.write()` is not used in this answer

Comment: Don't I need outfile.write() somewhere to actually output the file to a directory?

Comment: I have replaced print() with outfile.write(), also working in both cases.

Comment: Mia, "outfile.write(results)" and "print(results, file=outfile)" are redundant. They both do the same.

Comment: cricket_007 OP does not require to use outfile.write(), initial solution also solved the error, but I changed it anyway

Comment: Ah thanks, but when I run I do not see the 'testing.txt' file being generated. I though it would save in the directory I was running in.

Comment: Your initial version does not work because it throws an error. My version is working on my computer... if you still have issues, maybe is a problem with writting permissions or something different.

Comment: Also, my version throws an error if I use response.content (expected str instance, bytes found). With response.text is working fine. If this answer helped you, please mark as solved. Thanks.

Comment: Raul - you are correct I a was having write file permission errors

Comment: Thanks Mia, it's sad people are downvoting this answer. I still don't know what's wrong with it. I replicated an error, fixed it, tested it and published the working code so you could discard any code errors.